# gsutil - Find Files and Folders

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-dl-platform

Is there a `find` or `grep`-like command that I can use to search my Google Buckets?

I can only find [ls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls), but it is not quite what I need. I want to search for specific folder names and file names, that contain a certain string or match a certain regex.

Comment: The closest to a command to search is `gsutil ls -r gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[PREFIX]**` wich will let you search objects by a certain prefix. Otherwise you can elaborate a script to find specific names or prefix using as example this [Listing objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python) documentation.

Answer (score 10):

You can use your system `grep`:

```
gsutil ls gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/** | grep {string or regexp}
```

No need to use `-r` as `**` already flattens the folder structure.

Comment: Also useful: `gsutil ls gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/**/[FILE_NAME]`

Comment: @JonasBeck indeed it is - **however**, using simply the prefix followed by `grep` was significantly faster. I guess their server-side regex parsing lib is slower than `grep`'s

Answer (score 0):

Since `gsutil` tool is now obsolete, here is the new command

```
gcloud storage ls gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/** | grep {str or regex}
```

*note: my shell asks to escape * (star) character so for me it is*

```
gcloud storage ls gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/\*\* | grep {str or regex}
```